# Indentation Error. I'm at a complete loss

Tags: python

I've manually spaced out the whole thing. Still, it will not work. Indentation error directly after the first line.

The code:

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
""" docstring? """
losses = []
for d in data_loader:
    input_ids = d['input_ids'].to(device)
    targets = d['targets'].to(device)
    outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, labels = targets)
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
    losses.append( loss.item() )
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
return np.mean(losses)
```

The error:

def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
...

File "", line 2
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

What is going on? I don't see a problem anywhere.

Comment: indent the """docstring?""" line...or  better remove it,

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The problem is that the indentation is wrong – to be precise, that it is missing. Are you aware how indentation in Python is working?

Comment: "I've manually spaced out the whole thing....  I don't see a problem anywhere." It's hard to understand the reasoning here. In your own words: where the code says `losses = []`, how many spaces do you think are in front of that line? How many do you think there should be, and why?

Answer (score 0):

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
    """
    docstring?
    """
    losses = []
    for d in data_loader:
        input_ids = d['input_ids'].to(device)
        targets = d['targets'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, labels = targets)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        losses.append( loss.item() )
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    return np.mean(losses)
```

Please format it like this. Your code is not under the indentation block for your `train_epoch()` method.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the first line. The function's body has to be indented.

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
    """ docstring? """
    losses = []
    for d in data_loader:
        input_ids = d['input_ids'].to(device)
        targets = d['targets'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, labels = targets)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        losses.append( loss.item() )
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    return np.mean(losses)
```

Answer (score -1):

**for loop** must be indented to the right to make it function's code to run or inside the function,  else it will not be considered as function code.
Also **losses list** must be inside for loop not before it nor at the same for loop level for this case.

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
   
      
      for d in data_loader:
        losses = []
        input_ids = d['input_ids'].to(device)
        targets = d['targets'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, labels = targets)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        losses.append( loss.item() )
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        return np.mean(losses)
```